# Default Param value for Gin-Swagger

Tags: go, time, swagger, go-gorm, go-gin

I am using [gin-swagger](https://github.com/swaggo/gin-swagger) to prepare an `OpenAPI` for my `Go` project.

I have a `gorm` struct that includes a `time.Time` parameter called `Published`.

```
type Book struct {
    gorm.Model  `swaggerignore:"true"`
    Title       string    `json:"title" binding:"required" validate:"required" gorm:"size:255"`
    Published   time.Time `json:"published" validate:"lte"`
    ...
}
```

I am using swag as follows (regardless of the details).

```
//  @Summary        Add a new book
...
//  @Router         /books [post]
//
// AddBook handles the "POST /books" endpoint to create a new book.
func AddBook(c *gin.Context) {
  ...
}
```

The problem is that, when generating the swagger automatically, the `time.Time` is considered as a string. And hence, won't be accepted by the `gorm` struct (`Book`). The generated example value is:

```
{
  "title": "string",
  "published": "string",
  ...
}
```

Is there any way to let it handle `time.Time`? If not, can we put a default value for the `Book`, like say for example

```
// @Default {"Title": "How to implement a Library", "Published": "2023-09-15T10:00:00Z", ...}
```

Comment: It seems there is no build it solution: https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/3286

Comment: @meshkati, yeah, not even a default value.